# How to use Youtube DATA API in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, youtube-api

I have an application and i want to upload video direct from it to youtube using cakephp.
Or how can i use zend framework in cakephp.
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Google API as vendors and try

Answer (score 0):

You can using it. This link:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236502/upload-video-to-youtube-using-youtube-api-v3-and-php
```

Good luck.