# Upload video to Youtube using Youtube API V3 and PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client

I am trying to upload a video to Youtube using PHP. I am using Youtube API v3 and I am using the latest checked out source code of Google API PHP Client library.
I am using the sample code given on
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/ to perform the authentication. The authentication goes through fine but when I try to upload a video I get `Google_ServiceException` with error code 500 and message as null.

I had a look at the following question asked earlier:
[Upload video to youtube using php client library v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177266/upload-video-to-youtube-using-php-client-library-v3) But the accepted answer doesn't describe how to specify file data to be uploaded.
I found another similar question [Uploading file with Youtube API v3 and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954601/uploading-file-with-youtube-api-v3-and-php), where in the comment it is mentioned that categoryId is mandatory, hence I tried setting the categoryId in the snippet but still it gives the same exception.

I also referred to the Python code on the the documentation site ( https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert ), but I couldn't find the function next_chunk in the client library. But I tried to put a loop (mentioned in the code snippet) to retry on getting error code 500, but in all 10 iterations I get the same error.

Following is the code snippet I am trying:

```php
$youTubeService = new Google_YoutubeService($client);
if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    print "Successfully authenticated";
    $snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle = "My Demo title";
    $snippet->setDescription = "My Demo descrition";
    $snippet->setTags = array("tag1","tag2");
    $snippet->setCategoryId(23); // this was added later after refering to another question on stackoverflow

    $status = new Google_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "private";

    $video = new Google_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    $data = file_get_contents("video.mp4"); // This file is present in the same directory as the code
    $mediaUpload = new Google_MediaFileUpload("video/mp4",$data);
    $error = true;
    $i = 0;

    // I added this loop because on the sample python code on the documentation page
    // mentions we should retry if we get error codes 500,502,503,504
    $retryErrorCodes = array(500, 502, 503, 504);
    while($i < 10 && $error) {
        try{
            $ret = $youTubeService->videos->insert("status,snippet", 
                                                   $video, 
                                                   array("data" => $data));

            // tried the following as well, but even this returns error code 500,
            // $ret = $youTubeService->videos->insert("status,snippet", 
            //                                        $video, 
            //                                        array("mediaUpload" => $mediaUpload); 
            $error = false;
        } catch(Google_ServiceException $e) {
            print "Caught Google service Exception ".$e->getCode()
                  . " message is ".$e->getMessage();
            if(!in_array($e->getCode(), $retryErrorCodes)){
                break;
            }
            $i++;
        }
    }
    print "Return value is ".print_r($ret,true);

    // We're not done yet. Remember to update the cached access token.
    // Remember to replace $_SESSION with a real database or memcached.
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    print "<a href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
}
```

Is it something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post a stack trace? I suspect the issue is this: http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3961

Comment: I had seen that issue as well. When set resumable as true, then I get this exception "Uncaught exception 'Google_Exception' with message 'Failed to start the resumable upload" with error code 400, else it always gives error code 500 with message null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to get the upload working using the following code:

```
if($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
    $snippet->setDescription("Test descrition");
    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1","tag2"));
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    $status = new Google_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "private";

    $video = new Google_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    $error = true;
    $i = 0;

    try {
        $obj = $youTubeService->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video,
                                         array("data"=>file_get_contents("video.mp4"), 
                                        "mimeType" => "video/mp4"));
    } catch(Google_ServiceException $e) {
        print "Caught Google service Exception ".$e->getCode(). " message is ".$e->getMessage(). " <br>";
        print "Stack trace is ".$e->getTraceAsString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using your code but it does not upload the videos, should I add anything to the code ? I have added echo "obj:" .$obj; but it does not show anything.

Comment: Is there any exception that is thrown?

Comment: thanks for your response, I could solve the issue, it works but I can not upload large files, I am trying to use resumable upload but does not work do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm also trying to upload large files but i'm running in memory exceeded errors. How can I ensure the uploads are chunked? Does it matter that i'm using localhost to test?

Comment: Keyframe frequency: do not exceed 4 second

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2853702?hl=en&topic=2853713&ctx=topic

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is old, but here's the answer off the documentation:

```
    // REPLACE this value with the path to the file you are uploading.
    $videoPath = "/path/to/file.mp4";

    $snippet = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoSnippet();
    $snippet->setTitle("Test title");
    $snippet->setDescription("Test description");
    $snippet->setTags(array("tag1", "tag2"));

    // Numeric video category. See
    // https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list 
    $snippet->setCategoryId("22");

    // Set the video's status to "public". Valid statuses are "public",
    // "private" and "unlisted".
    $status = new Google_Service_YouTube_VideoStatus();
    $status->privacyStatus = "public";

    // Associate the snippet and status objects with a new video resource.
    $video = new Google_Service_YouTube_Video();
    $video->setSnippet($snippet);
    $video->setStatus($status);

    // Specify the size of each chunk of data, in bytes. Set a higher value for
    // reliable connection as fewer chunks lead to faster uploads. Set a lower
    // value for better recovery on less reliable connections.
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

    // Setting the defer flag to true tells the client to return a request which can be called
    // with ->execute(); instead of making the API call immediately.
    $client->setDefer(true);

    // Create a request for the API's videos.insert method to create and upload the video.
    $insertRequest = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video);

    // Create a MediaFileUpload object for resumable uploads.
    $media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
        $client,
        $insertRequest,
        'video/*',
        null,
        true,
        $chunkSizeBytes
    );
    $media->setFileSize(filesize($videoPath));


    // Read the media file and upload it chunk by chunk.
    $status = false;
    $handle = fopen($videoPath, "rb");
    while (!$status && !feof($handle)) {
      $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
      $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
    }

    fclose($handle);

    // If you want to make other calls after the file upload, set setDefer back to false
    $client->setDefer(false);
```

Comment: This is this exact example https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/resumable_upload.php in case someone found this answer and is curious about it.

Answer (score 2):

I also realize this is old, **but** as I cloned the latest version of php-client from GitHub I ran in to trouble with `Google_Service_YouTube_Videos_Resource::insert()`-method.

I would pass an array  with `"data" => file_get_contents($pathToVideo)` and `"mimeType" => "video/mp4"` set as an argument for the `insert()`-method, but I still kept getting **(400) BadRequest** in return.

Debugging and reading through Google's code i found in `\Google\Service\Resource.php` there was a check (on lines 179-180) against an array key  `"uploadType"` that would initiate the Google_Http_MediaFielUpload object.

```php
$part = 'status,snippet';
$optParams = array(
    "data" => file_get_contents($filename),
    "uploadType" => "media",  // This was needed in my case
    "mimeType" => "video/mp4",
);
$response = $youtube->videos->insert($part, $video, $optParams);
```

If I remember correctly, with version 0.6 of the PHP-api the uploadType argument wasn't needed. This might apply only for the *direct* upload style and not the *resumable* upload shown in Any Day's answer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer would be using Google_Http_MediaFileUpload through the [Google PHP client libraries](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

Here's the sample code: https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/resumable_upload.php