# Uploading video to Youtube using Youtube Data API V3 and Google API Client PHP -- getting 401 (unauthorized) message

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

I have to implement a way to upload video from our site to youtube. I already registered the app in Google Cloud and got all the necessary client ID, client secret code, browser key, redirect uri and server key. I also did turn ON the Youtube Data API V3, Google+ API, Freebase API and YouTube Analytics API as suggessted by various sites.

Here is my code below:

```
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_YouTubeService.php';

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Application Name');
    $client->setClientId('CLIENT_ID');
    $client->setClientSecret('CLIENT_SECRET_CODE');
    $client->setRedirectUri('REDIRECT_URI');
    $client->setDeveloperKey('DEVELOPER_KEY');

    $youtube = new Google_YouTubeService($client);
    if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
        $client->authenticate();
        $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
        $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
        header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['token'])){
        $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
    }

    if ($client->getAccessToken()){
        $path_to_video_to_upload = $_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"];
        $mime_type = $_FILES["video"]["type"];
        $snippet = new Google_VideoSnippet();
        $snippet->setTitle('Highlights');
        $snippet->setDescription('Description Of Video');
        $snippet->setTags(array('training', 'Soccer'));
        $snippet->setCategoryId(17);

        $status = new Google_VideoStatus();
        $status->privacyStatus = "private";

        $video = new Google_Video();
        $video->setSnippet($snippet);
        $video->setStatus($status);

        try {
            $obj = $youtube->videos->insert("status,snippet", $video,
            array("data"=>file_get_contents($path_to_video_to_upload), 
            "mimeType" => $mime_type));
            } catch(Google_ServiceException $e) {
            print "Caught Google service Exception ".$e->getCode(). " message is ".$e->getMessage()." <br>";
            }

    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    }

    else{
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            print "<a href='$authUrl'>Connect Me!</a>";
    }
```

I was referencing these codes from:
[Upload video to Youtube using Youtube API V3 and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236502/upload-video-to-youtube-using-youtube-api-v3-and-php)

and

http://www.dreu.info/blog/uploading-a-video-to-youtube-through-api-version-3-in-php/

First time I ran this code, it had me connect to the youtube account (with a screen asking to let google manage my YT account) and then on the second try, I got this 401 Message response.

Here's the response from youtube server

Caught Google service Exception 401 message is Error calling POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/youtube/v3/videos?part=status%2Csnippet&uploadType=multipart&key=AIzaSyCCySI5cToH3sICTmhCEFHW7QkIDptsjXg: (401) Unauthorized

I tried to search for various solutions but to no avail I cant seem to find it.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

follow-up question: Is the developer key the browser key or the server key? I am confused as to which should I use in my code. I've tried switching the keys and it also didn't work.

Comment: Your youtube account must be linked to your client google account. Can you login to youtube with your client credentials?

Comment: I had a similar issue. At the point of redirecting a user to the Google Authorization URL (`$client->createAuthUrl()`), I had to add the appropriate scopes to enable me to upload a video to upload on the client's behalf. `$client->setScope(['enter-scope-here'])` did it for me. I used to Google API playground to discover the scopes I needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.

Check your youtube account. Do you have a channel created? If you don't you wont be able to add videos (via API or even in youtube).

After creating the channel in youtube it worked. no need for new code or new keys.

Comment: Can you tell me, how to create the channel in youtube and how to use in the php code

Answer (score 0):

For Those who are getting the problem of `Access Not Configured. Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project`,

code by @justine1234 is working perfectly fine. Just remove

```
$client->setDeveloperKey('DEVELOPER_KEY');
```

and run it.

Thanks a lot for the code @justine1234.

Regards