# Google YouTube API v3 fails

Tags: api, youtube, youtube-data-api

## YouTube Data API: Upload Video

An error prevented the upload from completing.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.<UploadAsync>d__83.MoveNext() in C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis\Apis\[Media]\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:line 378
An error prevented the upload from completing.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: baseUri
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task)
   at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload`1.d__87.MoveNext() in C:\Users\mdril\Documents\GitHub\google-api-dotnet-client\Src\GoogleApis\Apis[Media]\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:line 460
Press any key to continue...

I have copied the example code to upload a video to youtube and I have installed my client_secret.json file and it does present me with a choice of which account to use.

The only other change was to place the actual name of the video file

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Has ANYONE successfully uploaded a video to YouTube using the YouTube Data API V3 from a .Net platform. If so, would you mind sharing your code that worked?

Answer (score 2):

After much searching I eventually then answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20189688/uploading-video-to-youtube-using-youtube-data-api-v3-and-google-api-client-php).
It turns out there was nothing wrong with the code but in order to upload to an account you MUST have created a YouTube Channel. While I can understand the restriction, it does occur to me that it could return a much more meaningful response. Judging by the amount of conversation it seems I am not the only one who had this problem.