# YouTube API v3 Video Upload Path using PHP and form

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

Trying to upload videos using V3 API from a form. When specifying the path to the video I'm using `$videoPath = file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["name"]);`  I've also tried it with out the `get_file_contents` and it tells me it can't find the file. I must be missing something, is there a way to upload directly from a form post without having to upload it to my server, than upload it to YouTube?

Comment: I'm not trying to download a video from Youtube, I'm trying to use the insert method to upload a video. If I set it to a file on the server it works fine. Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236502/upload-video-to-youtube-using-youtube-api-v3-and-php

Answer (score 0):

You dont allow to download video files from youtube dirrectly.
At first check path for `$_FILES["file"]["name"]`.

I recommend to use code if you need get information about video. After you may parse data and get images/video etc.

```
public function getParseVideo($code = null){
    $key = "your code";
      if(!empty($code)){
           $data = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?   key=".$key."&part=snippet&id=".$code);
                echo $json = json_decode($data);
            }
        }
```